# Why sub() and gsub() have the same results?

Tags: r, gsub

```
x <- c("This is a sentence about axis",
     "A second pattern is also listed here")

sub(".*is", "XY", x)
#[1] "XY"         "XYted here"

gsub(".*is", "XY", x)
#[1] "XY"         "XYted here"
```

Comment: If you call `?sub` in R, in the description it gives **`sub` and `gsub` perform replacement of the first and all matches respectively.**

Comment: Because `.*is` matches all up to the last occurrence of `is`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using the pattern `".*is"`, it matches everything from start of the string to the last `"is"`, which in first sentence is  `"is"` in `"axis"` and `"is"` in `"listed"` in 2nd string. Hence, everything upto that part gets replaced by `"XY"`.

What probably you might be expecting is :

```
sub("is", "XY", x)
#[1] "ThXY is a sentence about axis"        "A second pattern XY also listed here"

gsub("is", "XY", x)
#[1] "ThXY XY a sentence about axXY"        "A second pattern XY also lXYted here
```

As you can see in the `sub` call only the first `"is"` is replaced whereas in `gsub` all of the instances of `"is"` are replaced with `"XY"`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!